# Different chapters, different layout

Tags: book-design

On request, I have two different layouts for chapters for a book. The first one is exclusive to the Chapter 1 and the other one is for the others. The layout affect how the sections, definitions and paragraphs are displayed. I have the code to handle this in a little class file. This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{ifthen,calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\parindent=0mm

\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{axi}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\newcounter{definition}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=6pt,%
  spacebelow=6pt,%
  headfont=\normalfont\bf,%
  notefont=\normalfont\bf,
  notebraces={{}{}},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  headpunct={.}]{defistyle} 
\declaretheorem[
    name={Definition},
    numberlike=definition,
    style=defistyle]{defi}

\renewcommand\thesection
    {\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{
    {\csname the#1\endcsname}.\hspace{0.5em}}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection
    {section}{1}{0mm}                
    {6pt}                            
    {1pt}                            
    {\bfseries}}                     

\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection
    {paragraph}{3}{0cm}             
    {6pt}                           
    {1pt}                           
    {\bfseries}}                    
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\capi}[1]{
    \chapter{#1}
    \ifthenelse{\value{chapter}=2}{
        \renewcommand\section{\@startsection
        {section}{1}{0mm}               
        {0pt}                           
        {1pt}                           
        {\Large}}                       
        \@addtoreset{definition}{section}
        \renewcommand{\thedefi}{\thesection.\arabic{definition}}        
        }{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\capi{Some preliminaries}
\blindtext

\section{the first thing}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{defi}
The thing $1$ is real number. If $x$ is real then $x+1$ is real.
\end{defi}

\blindtext

\capi{Cool stuff}
\blindtext

\section{Complex things}
bla bla bla

\begin{defi}
We say that a number $x$ is complex if it is not really a number.
\end{defi}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

As you can see, my actual way to handle the different style for each chapter is not so elegant. I have the book splitted in several files, one per chapter. When I'm reviewing the book I'm select the chapters I want to see via the `\includeonly` command. The problem is that in order to get the proper look of the sections, paragraphs and definitions I always have to include the chapter 2. Also, I'll would like to avoid to define a new command to the chapters.  My question is: is there a way to improve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just define `\capi` to redefine itself when it's not the first chapter, so that the test and the redefinition will be performed only once.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\capi}{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    \changesectionanddefi
    \let\capi\chapter
  \fi
    \chapter
}
\def\changesectionanddefi{%
   \renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}{6pt}{1pt}{\Large}}%
   \@addtoreset{definition}{section}%
   \renewcommand{\thedefi}{\thesection.\arabic{definition}}%
}
\makeatother
```

You can even do better: redefine `\chapter` so as to get rid of the non standard `\capi` command:

```
\makeatletter
\let\leo@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 
    \changesectionanddefi 
    \let\chapter\leo@chapter
  \fi
    \leo@chapter
}
\def\changesectionanddefi{%
   \renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}{6pt}{1pt}{\Large}}%
   \@addtoreset{definition}{section}%
   \renewcommand{\thedefi}{\thesection.\arabic{definition}}%
}
\makeatother
```

So, no `\capi` with this, but the usual `\chapter`.

---

Be careful with end-of-lines in definitions. Also check the parameters to `\@startsection`: your code was not working correctly.

Comment: Now, it works, at least the MWE works. I have edited my question.

Comment: Why the condition is `\value{chapter}>0` instead of `\value{chapter}>1`?

Comment: @leo I've tested with `\includeonly` and it seems to do what's requested. The condition on `\value{chapter}` is because I put the test *before* the counter is incremented. So for the first `\capi` the counter value is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you use a suboptimal condition.  The condition is not that the chapter counter is equal to 2 but that the counter is greater than 1. Then the condition holds for all sections in all chapters. Thus you can then define `\section` to change its layout depending on the condition instead of placing the redefinition of `\section` inside the `\chapter` command.

Downside: the test will be executed whenever a section is processed (rather than only during chapter 2 once) but that is will not make a noticable difference in processing time.

Comment: I did it in that way precisely to avoid do the test whenever a section is processed. I mean, in an attempt to do the test only once when the chapter 2 is processed just for change things beginning with the chapter 2.

Comment: But then you create exactly the situation you want to avoid: you have something that is modified only in case chapter 2 is being processed. If you want to be able to process all chapters individually you either have to do the test in \section or do the redefinition whenever a \chapter is being processed. You can't have both.

Comment: Yes that was my problem. At some point I eventually resigned and then I opted for the way I did.